# Perform checksum to check if source table rows are loaded in target table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, etl, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to load data from old SQL Server 2000 to new SQL Server 2014. I need to do a checksum to check if all the source data is loaded in the target database (SQL Server 2014).

I've created the insert statement for the same which works. I need to use checksum to make sure all the source rows are loaded in the target table. Can somebody give me a hand on this?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Order_tab] 
    ([rec_id]
      ,[date_loaded]
      ,[Name1]
      ,[Name2]
      ,[Address1]
      ,[Address2]
      ,[City]
      ,[State]
      ,[Zipcode]
      ,[e_Name1])
      SELECT s.[rec_id]
      ,s.[date_loaded]
      ,s.[Name1]
      ,s.[Name2]
      ,s.[Address1]
      ,s.[Address2]
      ,s.[City]
      ,s.[State]
      ,s.[Zipcode]
      ,ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('EncryptionKey'),s.[Name1])
        FROM [LinkedServer].[SourceTest].[dbo].[Order_tab] s
        left join [Test].[dbo].[Order_tab] d on d.rec_id= s.rec_id
        where d.rec_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is a very naiv solution, but if you only need a one time check, it is fast :)

```
SELECT SUM([rec_id])
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order_tab]
```

And then compare it to:

```
SELECT SUM([rec_id])
FROM [LinkedServer].[SourceTest].[dbo].[Order_tab]
```

If you got everything over the `SUM` of the Id's should be the same :)